# What is the purpose of using `timestamp(nullif('',''))`

Tags: sql, oracle, db2

Folks

I am in the process of moving a decade old back-end from DB2 9.5 to Oracle 19c.

I frequently see in SQL queries and veiw definitions bizarre `timestamp(nullif('',''))` constructs used instead of a plain `null`.

What is the point of doing so? Why would anyone in their same mind would want to do so?

Disclaimer: my SQL skills are fairly mediocre. I might well miss something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to create a `NULL` value with a `TIMESTAMP` data type.

The [`TIMESTAMP` DB2 documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-timestamp) states:

> ### TIMESTAMP scalar function
>
> The TIMESTAMP function returns a timestamp from a value or a pair of values.
>
> ```
> TIMESTAMP(expression1, [expression2])
> ```

> #### expression1 and expression2
>
> The rules for the arguments depend on whether expression2 is specified and the data type of expression2.
>
> - If only one argument is specified it must be an expression that returns a value of one of the following built-in data types: a `DATE`, a `TIMESTAMP`, or a character string that is not a `CLOB`.

If you try to pass an untyped `NULL` to the `TIMESTAMP` function:

```sql
TIMESTAMP(NULL)
```

Then you get the error:

```
The invocation of routine "TIMESTAMP" is ambiguous. The argument in position "1" does not have a best fit.
```

To invoke the function, you need to pass one of the required `DATE`, `TIMESTAMP` or a non-`CLOB` string to the function which means that you need to coerce the `NULL` to have one of those types.

This could be:

```sql
TIMESTAMP(CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(14)))
TIMESTAMP(NULLIF('',''))
```

Using `NULLIF` is more confusing but, if I have to try to make an excuse for using it, is slightly less to type than casting a `NULL` to a string.

---

The equivalent in Oracle would be:

```sql
CAST(NULL AS TIMESTAMP)
```

This also works in DB2 (and is even less to type).

Comment: I think it's the most portable and straightforward way to create any type with `null` value.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear why - in any SQL dialect, no matter how old - one would use an argument like `nullif('','')`. Regardless of the result, that is a constant that can be calculated once and for all, and given as argument to `timestamp()`. Very likely, it should be `null` in any dialect and any version. So that should be the same as `timestamp(null)`. The code you found suggests that whoever wrote it didn't know what they were doing.

One might need to write something like that - rather than a plain `null` - to get `null` of a specific data type. Even though "theoretical" SQL says `null` does not have a data type, you may need something like that, for example in a view, to define the data type of the column defined by an expression like that.

In Oracle you can use the `cast()` function, as MT0 demonstrated already -  that is by far the most common and most elegant equivalent.

If you want something much closer in spirit to what you saw in that old code, `to_timestamp(null)` will have the same effect. No reason to write something more complicated for `null` given as argument, though - along the lines of that `nullif()` call.

Comment: `timestamp(null)` errors in DB2 with `The invocation of routine "TIMESTAMP" is ambiguous. The argument in position "1" does not have a best fit.`

Comment: I appreciate your input. I will go with `CAST(NULL AS TIMESTAMP)` as the most sensible option per @MTO recommendation.